# I cant format Sandisk Cruzer Edge USB: Read-Only filesystem

Tags: partitioning, usb

So, I have an old Sandisk Cruzer Edge 4GB USB drive, And I know how to format the usb, so I did what works for all USB drives, first, I used `fdisk -l` to find my USB's file-system. Heres what came up:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 4004 MB, 4004511744 bytes
124 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1017 cylinders, total 7821312 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000000

Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

So, I'm going on, I successfully unmounted the USB, then ran the command `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb`
I get the error:

```
user@user:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
mke2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/sdb is entire device, not just one partition!
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y

/dev/sdb: Read-only file system while setting up superblock
```

Please help? Thanks for any help!

PS: My USB doesn't show up in GParted, so don't tell me to try that please :)

Comment: `/dev/sdb is entire device, not just one partition!` tells you everything you need to know. You need to first create a partition (`/dev/sdb1`). I would tell you to use gparted, but you can also use `cfdisk /dev/sdb` if you prefer that. Then, `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1` will work

Comment: @noleti Alright, so I followed what you said, I put the usb into my computer, unmounted it and tried to create a partition using cfdisk (because like I said gparted doesn't find the usb). Heres what happened
`root@user cfdisk /dev/sdb`
`Opened disk Read-Only - You have no permission to write`
And from there all my changes inside cfdisk (even as root!) aren't saved and I still can't format the usb

Comment: @purbleguy Have you tried to use Chromebook/Windows to format the USB stick?

Answer (score 1):

When a pendrive or memory card is read-only

- On some pendrives and on many memory cards there is a small mechanical switch for write protection, that can toggle between read/write and read-only. You might have set it read-only without intention.
- Reboot the computer and try again to wipe the first megabyte with mkusb.
- Try other USB ports and another computer.
- If you still cannot wipe the first megabyte of the drive, and the drive is read-only, it is 'gridlocked', and the next stage is that it will be completely dead.

[Pendrive lifetime](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13199297#post13199297)

But there is still hope, because this symptom can also be caused by a severely damaged partition table. Try to wipe the first megabyte (overwrite with zeros). If this works, you can use gparted or another tool to create a partition table, and after that partitions again.

[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[wipe the first megabyte](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

If this does not work, the pendrive is damaged beyond repair (for normal users).

There are more details at the following link,

[Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could be a hardware bug of the SanDisk Cruzer Edge. A `sudo cfdisk /dev/sdb` should never return `Opened disk Read-Only - You have no permission to write`. Quick googling shows that this is a common problem. If you still have warranty, I would try to exchange the Cruzer.

Other related questions:

https://superuser.com/questions/661108/how-to-remove-write-protection-from-sandisk-cruzer-switch-pen-drive

Comment: Alright, I really dont mind not being able to use that. I have a working 16g pen drive, and that was a means to an end. Thanks for the help :)